# nginx : access.log and error.log file empty

Tags: nginx

I have just installed nginx on Ubuntu 14.04 using the command

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Now, when I open my browser and type in the address `localhost` then I am correctly shown the "Welcome to nginx" page. Also, I checked the config file located in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and found the following log settings:

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
```

However, when I check these two files, both are empty. I have opened the `localhost` page multiple times but still the log files are empty. What might be wrong with my setup ?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? having a similar issue here...

Comment: It worked later on without me changing anything.

Comment: having same issue no idea what's going on

Comment: I have this problem too. Nginx is started correctly but I don't see any page when I enter server IP address. and also I don't see any logs in access and error log.

Answer (score 65):

I had the same issue after reinstalling nginx to newer version. Seems like log files ownership changed and new nginx couldn't save anything there.

Removing log files and reloading nginx worked for me:

```
$ sudo rm -f /var/log/nginx/*
$ sudo nginx -s reload
```

Answer (score 15):

For all of those whose, like me, came here to figure out why the logs file are empty, and did not realise that you might actually be inside a docker container like one of the comments on another answer suggests, just open a new shell and tail the logs with

`docker logs {your-container-id-here} -f`

Comment: For docker user, if you concern where this behavior is set, visit this [Nginx Dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/Dockerfile-alpine.template), look for the comment `# forward request and error logs to docker log collector`

Answer (score 14):

It looks like by default they are set to go to stdout and stderr.

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   11 Apr 27  2016 access.log -> /dev/stdout
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   11 Apr 27  2016 error.log -> /dev/stderr
```

So you can remove the symlinks and should be fine.

```
rm -f /var/log/nginx/*
```

Comment: Someone must've set this for it to be used as Docker image

Comment: I'm using the official nginx docker image and this is what my problem was.  It does make great sense inside of docker, but that was a fun one to find lol

Comment: @Freedom_Ben i noticed the same for the official nginx docker image. Could you please help understand why it makes sense inside of docker? Will it be somehow routed to the host? If so, how can I make use of it? Thanks!

Comment: @Hans It makes sense in docker because stdout/stderr are the "proper" way to log.  In docker world files are a bad idea because they are ephemeral.  You want to follow 12-factor app principles

Comment: For docker user, if you concern where this behavior is set, visit this [Nginx Dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/Dockerfile-alpine.template), look for the comment `# forward request and error logs to docker log collector`

Answer (score 3):

By default Nginx image output the logs **access/error** to **stdout/stderr**.

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   11 Apr 27  2016 access.log -> /dev/stdout
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   11 Apr 27  2016 error.log -> /dev/stderr
```

We can also check the same by visit this [Nginx Dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/Dockerfile-alpine.template), look for the comment # forward request and error logs to docker log collector

**Now Use the below configuration in order to view the files.**

I have changed file name

*error.log = error.logs

access.log = access.logs*

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.logs notice;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.logs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is [here](http://techies-world.com/configure-nginx-to-send-logs-to-rsyslog/)

Step1: Open the rsyslog config file

```
#vi /etc/rsyslog.conf
```

Step2: Add the following line before the line `$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf`

```
$ModLoad imfile
```

Step3: Create a new file for nginx rsyslog configuration

```
#vi /etc/rsyslog.d/nginx.conf
```

Step4: Update the following lines.

```
# error log
$InputFileName /var/log/nginx/error.log
$InputFileTag nginx:
$InputFileStateFile stat-nginx-error
$InputFileSeverity error
$InputFileFacility local6
$InputFilePollInterval 1
$InputRunFileMonitor

# access log
$InputFileName /var/log/nginx/access.log
$InputFileTag nginx:
$InputFileStateFile stat-nginx-access
$InputFileSeverity notice
$InputFileFacility local6
$InputFilePollInterval 1
$InputRunFileMonitor
```

Step5: Restart rsyslog service

```
#service rsyslog restart
```