# How does one debug an unresponsive, nebulous Werkzeug 404 Error?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, werkzeug

We're using a Flask app, served by gunicorn + Nginx in a docker container. Roughly once or twice every 24 ours, our logger displays the following message:

```
Dec 31 00:27:36 Computer logger: [12/31/2019 08:27:36] backend ERROR:   404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request     rv = self.dispatch_request()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1925, in dispatch_request     self.raise_routing_exception(req)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1907, in raise_routing_exception     raise request.routing_exception   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/ctx.py", line 350, in match_request     result = self.url_adapter.match(return_rule=True)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1799, in match     import pdb werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

What this affects or what it's caused by is totally mysterious, and the traceback is not helpful in the slightest. There is no noticeable change on the user-facing side. I've tried many things, including starting the app. in debug mode. My most recent attempt was to go into `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py` itself and change the behavior of the error. What happens, though, is that above-logged message just prints out my code changes—but doesn't seem to actually run the changes themselves. (i.e. - Everything looks to run exactly the same way, regardless of how I change that file. Instead, the changes themselves are logged [not the effects of running that changed code]).

How does one debug an unresponsive Werkzeug 404 error like this? What options/settings/methods am I missing? Why would changes to the code of `routing.py` (for example) be ignored, but printed out to the screen (as if what Python is doing is just printing out code blocks between `line x` and `line y`).

Comment: Can you look in the Nginx logs for request URLs that produced 404s?

Comment: @Ry- good idea! I checked, but ran into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299582/nginx-access-log-and-error-log-file-empty) problem, so I've got to wait 'til the error pops up again. :l